# How to use string as key for array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript problem:

```
let classStart: keyof typeof monday;
const now = new Date();
console.log(now.getHours());
for (let i = Object.keys(monday).length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  let time: any = Object.keys(monday)[i].split(":");
  // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
  if (time[0] == now.getHours()) {
    if (time[1] <= now.getMinutes()) {
      console.log(Object);
      classStart = Object.keys(monday)[i];
      console.log();
    } else {
      //classStart = Object.keys(monday)[i - 1];
      console.log(Object.keys(monday)[i - 1]);
    }

    // console.log(monday[classStart]);
  }
}
```

This is my code, I need to use the Object.keys(monday)[i] (which is a string) as a property for monday[].

If I use the `let classStart: keyof typeof monday;` I can assign e.x "7:25" to classStart but I can't assign it using a function like `Object.keys(monday)[i];`. Why?

The JSON where I get the data from looks like this:

```
    ...
    "7:25": ["B1", "B2", "B3","B4"],
    ...
```

It is a typescript problem. I'm quite sure.

Comment: The keys in an array are numbers. You can't use a string. Do you want an object? `Object.keys` returns the keys of an array as strings.

Comment: Yes, I want an Object. My problem is, that it works if I use `monday["7:25"]` but not If i use `Object.keys(monday)[i];`

Comment: If the string contains a number simply convert it, for example `+time[0]` (note the `+`). However that code is waaaay to convolute even if it's so short. I'd refactor it to something easier to read (where the _error_ will also be clear). Also, why do you need `any` when the inferred type is absolutely fine? When types get in your way, usually, you're doing something you do not _want_ to do.

Comment: Is `monday` an array or an object?

Comment: It is a object imported from json
"7:25": ["B1", "B2", "B3","B4"]

Comment: What is `monday`? Is it the array `["B1", "B2", "B3","B4"]` or the object `{"7:25": ["B1", "B2", "B3","B4"]}`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think the problem is that `keyof typeof monday;` doesn't return `'string'`. It returns `'7:25'` as a type. That's a subset of `string`. At least that's the problem in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtuAJgQwJ4wLwwN4CIDsAXAEwCsuhMA2rgEICMuANDHcc67QMzN0AsuALoBfANwAocQBsAprGBTkECAGUoyAE5RKAaxmoQAMxhRUABxlH4SNBIVLV6rZhgB5AEYArGcCgA6PVQIAAoEMBRUAEoqAAZBCXEwiKp7ZTVNKEEgA

Comment: How would you fix it?

Comment: You can specify the type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtuAJgQwJ4wLwwN4CIDsAXAEwCsuhMA2rgEICMuANDHcc67QMzN0AsuALoBfANwAocVFQAHAKYwAskjSYYAazmoQAMxjT5u+CtQSANnNjAzyCBADKUZACcolZWBSnx12w6euagDyAEYAVnLAUAB0mqgQABQInmgAlFQADIIwtkomEuLJXlS+do4uUIJAA

Comment: Could you share `monday`? Or even better, can you make your code run at https://www.typescriptlang.org and post the link here?

Comment: @jabaa Thank you alot! Now it works like expectetd

Comment: @Elias I found the solution. It is on the link of Jabaa. In the future I will do it like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem, that no one can guess what is the type of *monday*, (TypeScript too).
So if you specify its type, the problem will become much more clearer

I suspect that

```
monday: {
   [HHMM:string]: string[]
}
```

So I slightly altered your code

```
const mondayInput = {
    "10:13": ["B1"],
    "7:25": ["B1", "B2", "B3","B4"]
};
const monday = mondayInput as Record<string,string[]>

//fixed date time for test proposes
let now = new Date("2013/01/01 10:10:00")
console.log(now, now.getHours(),  now.getMinutes());

function HHMMtoInt(x:string){const [HH, MM] = x.split(":"); return parseInt(HH) * 100 + parseInt(MM)}
const times = Object.keys(monday).sort((a,b) => HHMMtoInt(a)-HHMMtoInt(b));

for (let i = 0;i < times.length; i++) {
  const  timeHHMM = times[i]; 

  let time = timeHHMM.split(":").map(x => parseInt(x));

  let timeInterval: number | undefined;
  console.log("Compare", time[0], time[1], now.getHours(), now.getMinutes())
  if (time[0] == now.getHours()) {
    if (time[1] <= now.getMinutes()) {
        timeInterval = i;
    } else {
        timeInterval = i - 1; 
    }
  }
  
  if(timeInterval !== undefined && timeInterval >= 0 ){
      console.log("Time", times[timeInterval], "Classes", monday[times[timeInterval]] );
  }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtuAJgQwJ4EkwAcCusC8MA3gFAzkwBEAjAAwBc1AzJfTANqUBC1lAugBoyFSgHZ6AJgCsrDt14CqXCZUXcWA7gBZ+JAL4BuEqEiwEYFKhiFzlzLljIIMAEoBTUACdEAHmieASzAAcwF-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-Ee8UcjFiSpYVvEGQBD2FB6DAbjxESv7-v+gEFOWlZgTASq1KG-4UuQOEwMIh5PtGJYoaBACE54thY7adogMAAGT0RGJEgTA0SELQMBvH+vaQP2g79JQAAq0ZTgGEDsEhwGVnOlDDvEThEhAU58qgknRhJUmkXwfxarh+hAA)

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped me. I will adapt it and add it to my project. For future questions I will give more context. I am sorry for that. 
Thank you very much for your time